# Issues Creating Custom Rails Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with the following structure:

- A `mealplan` includes one `recipe` for each day of the week.
- A `recipe` `has_many` `ingredients`.
- A `grocery` is one item on the user's grocery list.

I want to create a custom method so that when a button is clicked, it runs `Grocery.create` on each `ingredient` from the `recipes` on the `mealplan`.

I currently have the following `mealplans#index` method, so you can see how they're defined.  (All of this is happening on the `index` view:

```
  def index
    @mealplans = Mealplan.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @mealplan = Mealplan.new
    @recent = Mealplan.where(user_id: current_user.id).where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).order("week_starting").last
    @recipes = Recipe.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @monday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.monday)[0] if @recent.present?
    @tuesday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.tuesday)[0] if @recent.present?
    @wednesday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.wednesday)[0] if @recent.present?
    @thursday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.thursday)[0] if @recent.present?
    @friday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.friday)[0] if @recent.present?
    @saturday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.saturday)[0] if @recent.present?
    @sunday = Recipe.where(id: @recent.sunday)[0] if @recent.present?
  end
```

I also have a dummy `mealplans#add_to_list` method set up in the controller, but I feel like doing it this way violates the "skinny controllers, fat models" principle of rails.

Can anyone clue me in to the "railsiest" way to accomplish this task, according to best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `gem "nested_form"` gem for creating multiple records.

For better implementation create scope under Mealplan model.

```
class Mealplan < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :recent, ->(uid) { where(user_id: uid).where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).order("week_starting").last}

   # find the day name of recent Mealplan
   def recent_day_name
     created_at.strftime("%A")
   end
end
```

In controller you can use this scope like this:

```
def index
  @mealplan = Mealplan.new
  @recent = Mealplan.recent(current_user.id)
  if @recent
    recent_day = @recent.recent_day_name
    @day = Recipe.find(id: @recent.send(recent_day))
  end
end
```

There is no needs to create `@mealplans` and `@recipes` instance variable on controller site:

```
@mealplans = Mealplan.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@recipes = Recipe.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

You can get the mealplans and recipes details from current_user object.

Comment: This scope gives me errors.  It seems to have an issue with the `|uid|` bit, saying `syntax error, unexpected '|'`

Comment: Try this.
`scope :recent, ->(uid) {  where(user_id: uid).where("created_at > ?", Time.now.beginning_of_week).order("week_starting").last }`

Comment: Beautiful!  That makes it much DRYer.